# Forward declaration of class variable

Tags: c++, inheritance, forward-declaration

Can i forward declare class variable in other class to avoid circular dependency and if yes, how?
Example:

```
//another file
class Engine;
extern vector<Block*> Engine::MapBlocks;

//Engine.h
class Engine
{
public:
   vector<Block*> MapBlocks;
};
```

Its possible?

Comment: Nope won't work

Comment: C++ doesn't have partial classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, what you're trying to do is not possible. It is not possible to declare non-static class members outside the class definition.   If such a thing was allowed, it would allow any code to arbitrarily modify any class (e.g. by declaring a member that is not actually part of the class).   Logically, that breaks the intent of using classes (e.g. encapsulation) totally.

However, it is possible to pass and store pointers to a class type, without the definition being visible.   In this case

```
#include <vector>     // necessary for use of std::vector

class Block;

class Engine
{
   public:
     std::vector<Block*> MapBlocks;

      // preferably declare constructors and/or other member functions
      //    that initialise MapBlocks appropriately to needs
};
```

This will work because the compiler does not need to have visibility of the definition of `Block` to store pointers in a container.

Naturally, any code which attempts to instantiate a `Block`  (e.g. `some_engine.MapBlocks.push_back(new Block)`) or call its member functions (e.g. `some_engine.MapBlocks[some_valid_index]->some_member_function()`) relies on visibility of a definition of class `Block`, not just a forward declaration.

Answer (score 3):

## No

Your class declaration has to be complete, you cannot split it or partially declare it.

*If you asked about the real problem you encountered, we might be able to help you anyway. Most likely there is a solution, just not to this abstract question.*